# how to send this soap request?

Tags: php, soap

I have soap request parameters this:

```
<soap:Body>
<GetProductList xmlns="http://schemas.acme.eu/">
<GetProductListRequest>
<Filters>
<Filter>
<Name>Language</Name>
<Value>lt-lt</Value>
</Filter>
<Filter>
<Name>Currency</Name>
<Value>LTL</Value>
</Filter>
</Filters>
</GetProductListRequest>
</GetProductList>
</soap:Body>
```

I try to send request like this:

```
    $result = $client->GetProductList(array('Filters' => array(
                    'Filter'=> array('Name' => 'Language', 'Value' => 'lt-lt'), 
                    'Filter'=> array('Name' => 'Currency', 'Value' => 'LTL'))));
```

But I get error here:

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:Server] Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object. in C:\wamp\www\tarpine_xml\class\acme_xml.php:25 Stack trace: #0 C:\wamp\www\tarpine_xml\class\acme_xml.php(25): SoapClient->__call('GetProductList', Array) #1 C:\wamp\www\tarpine_xml\class\acme_xml.php(25): SoapClient->GetProductList(Array) #2 C:\wamp\www\tarpine_xml\index.php(18): ACME_XML->parseACME() #3 {main} thrown in C:\wamp\www\tarpine_xml\class\acme_xml.php on line 25
```

Other requests without parameters works fine.. So where is mistake in my request?

**SOLVED**

I have create this code:

```
    $parrams['GetProductListRequest']['Filters']['Filter']  = array();
    $parrams['GetProductListRequest']['Filters']['Filter'][] = array('Name' => 'Language', 'Value' => 'lt-lt');
    $parrams['GetProductListRequest']['Filters']['Filter'][] = array('Name' => 'Currency', 'Value' => 'LTL');
    $result = $client->GetProductList($parrams);
```

And it works perfectly :)

Comment: Don't know which library you're using, but you're obviously doing something wrong when you're defining twice the entry 'Filter' in your parameter...

Comment: I using $client = new SoapClient("https://api.acme.lt/1.0/commerce.asmx?wsdl"); this method

Answer (score 1):

Not familiar with this FW, but i think you need to add `GetProductListRequest` to the request as well (this is the root xml tag).

So you should have something like:

```
$result = $client->GetProductList(array('GetProductListRequest'=>array('Filters' => array(
                    'Filter'=> array('Name' => 'Language', 'Value' => 'lt-lt'), 
                    'Filter'=> array('Name' => 'Currency', 'Value' => 'LTL')))));
```

Comment: you where right with item GetProductListRequest, but not with all request :)

Answer (score 0):

Small fix

```
$params['GetProductList']['GetProductListRequest']['Filters']['Filter']  = array();
$params['GetProductList']['GetProductListRequest']['Filters']['Filter'][] = array('Name' => 'Language', 'Value' => 'lt-lt');
$params['GetProductList']['GetProductListRequest']['Filters']['Filter'][] = array('Name' => 'Currency', 'Value' => 'LTL');
```